# Error python AtributeError: str object has no tribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

estoy haciendo un ejercicio con Python y poo, el problema es que me sale:

> AtributeError: str object has no tribute 'borrarUsuario'

No entiendo por qué sale este error, el código es el siguiente:

```
class Usuarios:
    def __init__(self,nombre,contrasenya,email):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contrasenya = contrasenya
        self.email = email

    def borrarUsuario(nombre,contrasenya,email):
        nombre = 'No existen usuarios'
        contrasenya = 'No hay contrasenyas almacenadas'
        email = 'Ningun email almacenado'
        return nombre, contrasenya, email


usuario_1 = Usuarios('JayZ', '123456', 'jayz@gmail.com')
print(usuario_1.nombre.borrarUsuario)
print(usuario_1.contrasenya.borrarUsuario)
print(usuario_1.email.borrarUsuario)
```

**Actualización:**

```
class Usuarios: 
    def __init__(self,nombre,contrasenya,email): 
        self.nombre = nombre 
        self.contrasenya = contrasenya 
        self.email = email 
    
    def borrarUsuario(nombre,contrasenya,email): 
        nombre = 'No existen usuarios' 
        contrasenya = 'No hay contrasenyas almacenadas' 
        email = 'Ningun email almacenado' 
        return nombre, contrasenya, email 

usuario_1 = Usuarios('JayZ', '123456', 'jayz@gmail.com') 
print(usuario_1.borrarUsuario(nombre)) 
print(usuario_1.borrarUsuario(contrasenya)) 
print(usuario_1.borrarUsuario(email))
```

Comment: `borrarUsuario` es un método, luego para llamarlo debes usar `()` --> `borrarUsuario()`. Además, lo llamas desde `usuario_1.contrasenya`, cuando `.contrasenya` es un atributo de `usuario_1`. Probablemente quieras decir `usuario_1.borrarUsuario()`. A todo esto, ¿por qué pasar los parámetros `nombre` y `contrasenya` al método `borrarUsuario` si ya los tienes vía `self`?

Comment: Hola. Creo que tienes un problema teórico con respecto a la POO. Una cosa son atributos (`nombre`, `email`, etc.) y otra son los métodos (`borrarUsuario`). Lo que estás tratando de hacer es llamar al método a través de los atributos, y eso no funciona así. Lo que tienes que hacer es llamar al método de tu instancia `usuario_1`: `usuario_1.borrarUsuario()`. No necesitas pasarle los parámetros porque los puedes referir desde la misma clase, también te faltan los paréntesis al llamar al método, es `borrarUsuario()`, no `borrarUsuario` a secas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con el código. Veamos por partes:

**Primero**. Entiendo que el método `borrarUsuario` tiene por objetivo eliminar la información del usuario sin borrar el objeto:

```
def borrarUsuario(nombre, contrasenya, email):
    nombre = 'No existen usuarios'
    contrasenya = 'No hay contrasenyas almacenadas'
    email = 'Ningun email almacenado'
    return nombre, contrasenya, email
```

La variable `nombre` dentro método es una variable local. Lo que tú deseas es cambiar `self.nombre`, la variable del objeto.

Estas recibiendo tres parametros que no usas. Eliminalos.

Te falta `self` como argumento del método. Los métodos de una clase siempre tienen como primer argumento `self`, que es una referencia al objeto en particular al cual aplicas el método. Si no pones `self`, el método no se aplica va a cambiar ningún objeto.

Estas retornando los parametros que recibistes. No tiene sentido.

**Segundo**. El método borrarUsuario lo declaraste con tres parametros y lo estás llamando sólo con uno.

```
print(usuario_1.borrarUsuario(nombre))
```

**Tercero**. En Python (y cualquier otro languaje OO) lo que se hace es eliminar el objeto por completo, con

```
del usuario1
```

Mientras no lo elimines, el objeto usuario1 sigue existiendo y ocupando espacio en memoria. Más aún, tendrás un objeto dando vuelta que no tiene ninguna utilidad.

Esta es tu código con los problemas corregidos:

```
class Usuarios:
    def __init__(self,nombre,contrasenya,email):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contrasenya = contrasenya
        self.email = email

    def borrarUsuario(self):
        self.nombre = 'No existen usuarios'
        self.contrasenya = 'No hay contrasenyas almacenadas'
        self.email = 'Ningun email almacenado'
        return self.nombre, self.contrasenya, self.email



usuario_1 = Usuarios('JayZ', '123456', 'jayz@gmail.com')
print(usuario_1.nombre)
print(usuario_1.contrasenya)
print(usuario_1.email)
usuario_1.borrarUsuario()
print(usuario_1.nombre)
print(usuario_1.contrasenya)
print(usuario_1.email)
```

Produce:

```
JayZ
123456
jayz@gmail.com
No existen usuarios
No hay contrasenyas almacenadas
Ningun email almacenado
```

Finalmente, la versión correcta de tu código sería:

```
class Usuarios:
    def __init__(self,nombre,contrasenya,email):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contrasenya = contrasenya
        self.email = email


usuario_1 = Usuarios('JayZ', '123456', 'jayz@gmail.com')
print(usuario_1.nombre)
print(usuario_1.contrasenya)
print(usuario_1.email)
del usuario_1
```

Comment: Gracias lo he entenido y me ha funcionado, no sabia la existencia de del y es lo mejor y mas practico

Comment: @Alvarog, si te ha servido la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.